# basic android scroll bars not visible

Tags: android, textview, scrollbar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Choose Details"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Year"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Branch"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Semester"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am bit new to android.Could anyone tel me that why arent the three scroll bars visible along the text views.I want to display the scrolls adjacent to their respective textviews.Moreover is the relative layout the best way to align the widgets .

Answer (score 1):

Until and unless, you add `View` element in `ScrollView`, the `ScrollView`s which u have added cannot be visible, but they are present in `layout`. `ScrollView` must contain a single `View` item either it is a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` with child views such as `TextView`, `ImageView`, `EditText`, `Button` as below:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

or a `View` element as a single child for `ScrollView` as below:

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks @RaghuRamiReddy . I hope the person who asked question can understand what i have explained here and accepts the answer..!!!

Comment: @user2474232 do u find the solution??

Answer (score 0):

A scroll view is not a scroll bar.

It must contain some elements.

Example :

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Your code should be

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Choose Details"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Year"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Branch"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Semester"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <ScrollView/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, set `android:orientation="vertical"`

2) Put the textview inside your scrollview, like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

If you put all textviews inside a single scrollview, you will have one scrollbar(Note however that scrollview can only contain one child view, so you'll need to wrap those textviews under a linear layout); if you put one text view in each scrollview and stack those scrollviews vertically in linear layout, then you'll have separate scrollbar for each textview.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollView` in your layout is not visible because your it does not contain any widget with `height` and `width`. If you want to see your `ScrollView` then you have to set some value to the `width` and `height` (for example `android:layout_width="40dip"`) properties, and a `backgroundColor()`, after this you will able to see you `ScrollView`.